# Convert jpeg sequence to movie stream, in realtime, using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a process that is creating a jpeg every X seconds. I know it's possible to use `ffmpeg` to convert a set of jpgs to a movie, but I want to do it in real-time because I am trying to stream it to a url (YouTube Live).

Is this possible? Are there other tools that could help?

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG can be stream in 2 ways,

1. stream to some other server which can re-streams for it to multiple clients
2. stream via UDP/TCP directly to some single destination receiver

[ffserver](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver), [Wowza media server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wowza_Media_Server) etc can receive from FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0):

`man 1 ffmpeg` says:

> For creating a video from many images:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -s WxH foo.avi
> ```
>
> The syntax "foo-%03d.jpeg" specifies to use a decimal number
>   composed of three digits padded with zeroes to express the
>   sequence number. It is the same syntax supported by the C printf
>   function, but only formats accepting a normal integer are
>   suitable.
>
> When importing an image sequence, -i also supports expanding
>   shell-like wildcard patterns (globbing) internally, by selecting
>   the image2-specific "-pattern_type glob" option.
>
> For example, for creating a video from filenames matching the
>   glob pattern "foo-*.jpeg":
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -framerate 12 -i 'foo-*.jpeg' -s WxH foo.avi
> ```

[Here's](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) the documentation for ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the documentation. I'm trying to stream photos, in real time, as they appear in a directory. I.e. Not a one-off batch job.